# assign a specific value to an array element using a MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, ranking

The idea is to run a sort of ranking MySQL command such as:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT f_score FROM ".TBL_FACTIONS." ASC");
```

EDIT: I do need to add a WHERE f_id = $id in here too.

> The numeric value in my MySQL database table in the *f_score* column should determine the rank.
>   f_score contains only numeric values, from 0 to anything, user actions add and subtract from the score.

then use the $sql to loop through an array and "rank" each array element.
I think it should assign a number to a specific variable so I can echo the number out on the webpage.

> E.g. *Your rank is: 01*

I'm looking for something lightweight, but if its not possible to do this win minimum server usages, I'll have to shove it into a cron job or something which isn't really ideal.
I was thinking along the lines of array and loops or something similar?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

-Callum

Comment: I think you should rephrase the question a bit, its not clear what defines the rank.

Comment: @Sabeen Malik: Have I made it any clearer now?

Comment: I think you should explain what the array looks like and what does the f_score hold. Also the query doesnt seem right, will it contain a where clause based on some value already in the array?

Comment: What will be stored in f_score? 01, 02, 03 etc.??

Comment: Added a little more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT f_name FROM ".TBL_FACTIONS." ORDER BY f_score DESC");
$i = 1;

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    echo "{$row['f_name']} & Rank: {$i}<br>";
    $i++;
}
```

Will output:

```
Bla bla & Rank: 1
Foo bar & Rank: 2
Etc.
```

The SQL for the rank of a specific record is a bit complicated.
You could try the following:

```
// E.g. rank for f_id = 123
$id = 123;

$sql = "
SELECT `a`.`rank` + `b`.`rank` AS `rank`
FROM (SELECT COUNT(*)+1 AS `rank`
    FROM ".TBL_FACTIONS."
    WHERE `f_score` > (SELECT `f_score`
        FROM ".TBL_FACTIONS."
        WHERE `f_id` = {$id})) AS `a`
STRAIGHT_JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS `rank`
    FROM ".TBL_FACTIONS."
    WHERE `f_score` = (SELECT `f_score`
        FROM ".TBL_FACTIONS."
        WHERE `f_id` = {$id}) AND `f_id` < {$id}) AS `b`
";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
echo "{$id} is ranked {$row[0]}";
```

I found the query [here](http://www.kirupa.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-263260.html) and it makes sense, but please test thoroughly if the results you get are what you expect it to be.

Alternatively, if your recordset is not too big, you could just loop through the results and break out of the loop when you get to the ID you are looking for:

```
$id = 123;
$result = mysql_query("SELECT f_id FROM ".TBL_FACTIONS." ORDER BY f_score DESC");
$i = 1;

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    if($row['f_id'] == $id)
    {
        echo "{$row['f_id']} is ranked {$i}<br>";
        break;
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: yeah, your right actually. Bummer, i forgot to think about that :/

Erm, I need to add a WHERE f_id = $id in there to display it correctly for the selected faction.

Comment: also, knowing how to show who is ranked 1,2,3 would be really useful for another part of the webpage actually

Comment: I still don't understand what you are trying to do here. Do you want something like: `Faction ID 23 - your rank is: 1`. What exactly do you want to show on the webpage?

Comment: Its meant to show:  $name & Rank: $rank.  Where name is a value taken from the f_name column (i've already got that assigned to a variable) and $rank is the numeric value that this ranking script assigns, and echos, for the factions id based upon the numeric score in the f_score column.

Comment: If i could get a way to echo faction id: ranked 1. Where the ranked value assigned to this id from the f_score value. I could take it from there?

Comment: Now I updated my code to show `$name & Rank: $rank`. There is no need to assign f_name to a variable. Just try the code in my answer. Please stop posting conflicting comments. What do you want to show -- the ID and the rank or the name and the rank??

Comment: what you have posted is what I was looking for. Question answered. Thank you for your time.

I do have one question, could I modify this code to only display one specific id's rank and not echo the others?

Comment: By the way, shouldn't the faction with the highest score be ranked 1? If you use `ORDER BY f_score ASC`, the faction with the lowest score will be ranked 1.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up!  Silly mistake of mine, i'll change it to DESC then :)

Comment: "I do have one question, could I modify this code to only display one specific id's rank and not echo the others?"

Comment: I added the modification you are looking for

Comment: @Callum Johnson: The COUNT subselect has a flaw - if there are duplicates, they will have the same rank/position value.  IE: If two are tied for second place, the rank will be "2" for both of them.

Comment: trying the first explanation works perfectly if f_id is simply a numeric value. It throws a boolean error if a aplha numeric is used as f_id, any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: @OMG Ponies: What is the best way to modify it to then rank by alphabetical order if the scores and subsequently the ranks are equal?

Comment: just add single quotes around `{$id}` if it's not an integer: `'{$id}'`